# Generating fractal Swirl

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, fractals

I need to draw a fractal swirl using the algorithm [Iterated Function System](http://www.stsci.edu/~lbradley/seminar/ifs.html).

[image: Targeted Fractal Image]

There are coefficients for this fractal:

```
0.745455 -0.459091  0.406061  0.887121 1.460279 0.691072 0.912675
-0.424242 -0.065152 -0.175758 -0.218182 3.809567 6.741476 0.087325
```

And here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Surface extends JPanel {
double a1 = 0.745455;
double b1 = -0.459091;
double d1 = 0.406061;
double e1 = 0.887121;
double c1 = 1.460279;
double f1 = 0.691072;
double p1 = 0.912675;

double a2 = -0.424242;
double b2 = -0.065152;
double d2 = -0.175758;
double e2 = -0.218182;
double c2 = 3.809567;
double f2 = 6.741476;
double p2 = 0.087325;

double x1(double x, double y) {
    return a1 * x + b1 * y + c1;
}

double y1(double x, double y) {
    return d1 * x + e1 * y + f1;
}

double x2(double x, double y) {
    return a2 * x + b2 * y + c2;
}

double y2(double x, double y) {
    return d2 * x + e2 * y + f2;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    drawFractal(g);
}

void drawFractal(Graphics g) {
    double x1 = 300;
    double y1 = 300;
    double x2 = 0;
    double y2 = 0;
    g.fillOval(300 + (int) x1, 300 + (int) y1, 3, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        double p = Math.random();
        if (p < 0.91675) {
            x2 = x1(x1, y1);
            y2 = y1(x1, y1);
            g.fillOval(300 + (int) x2, 300 + (int) y2, 3, 3);
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
        } else {
            x2 = x2(x1, y1);
            y2 = y2(x1, y1);
            g.fillOval(300 + (int) x2, 300 + (int) y2, 3, 3);
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately, with this code I get a wrong picture:

[image: Current Fractal Image]

It would be great if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: This is not so much a Java question as an algorithm question. What algorithm are you using? Can you link us to a reference to where you obtained this algorithm?

Comment: It seems from the output that you're always using the same transformation or missing one.

Comment: Are the coefficients correct and complete?

Comment: The naming collision between a local variable and a method is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I'm using iterated function system. I've added link

Comment: what happen when you iterate not only 10000 but 100K times or 1M times

Comment: Jan Dvorak, I'm using first transformation if generated value is less then 0.91675, and second if its more

Comment: Jan Dvorak, I can't change probabilities, they are stated coefficients for this fractal

Comment: UmNyobe, 100k - http://s14.postimage.org/eoweh1zkx/100000.png, 1M - http://s1.postimage.org/y9wpano3z/1000000.png

Comment: I've got them from task at university, also I've seen it here http://fractalworld.xaoc.ru/IFS_collection (look for "swirl")

Comment: @Nostia on the above site the ordering seems to be "a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 p1", however you seem to be listing them in a different order. Look at  d1 and c1 for example.

Comment: cmh, but on that site there are formulas x = ax+by+e, y = cx+dy+f. I use  x = ax+by+c , y = dx+ey+f;

Comment: Try if renaming the methods to not collide with variable names helps.

Comment: Any chance the randomness generator is not too random?

Comment: Try printing the sequence of branches taken to see if it complies with expectations.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've found one mistake, instead of x1 = x2; y1 = y2; there should be  x1 = x2 +300; y1 = y2 +300; because I start from point (300,300). Now it looks better, but it is still wrong http://s1.postimage.org/coh3wzaa7/Screen_Shot_2012_12_23_at_15_53_05.png

Comment: Why not stick to the letters and orders used on the site? It's hard for people to check the way it is and is very possibly the source of the error.

Comment: @Nostia thanks for the fractal collection, by the way

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your generation seems correct (i.e. don't do `x1 = x2 +300; y1 = y2 +300;`), but your problem is you're way off the scale for the purposes of rendering. This means there are very few points that fall outside very center of the image.

Your window is `[0..600]x[0..600]`. Try multiplying `x2` and `y2` with 50, so that you're rendering the `[-6..6]x[-6..6]` region instead of the `[-300..300]x[-300..300]` region of space.

Note that it should be sufficient to draw single pixels (as lines to itself) instead of 3x3 ovals.

```
int xp = 300 + (int) (x2 * scale);
int yp = 300 + (int) (y2 * scale);
g.drawLine(xp, yp, xp, yp);
```

Depending on what gets rendered, you might need to adjust the scale slightly to get the entire image with reasonable bounds. Note the second transformation offsets by `-6.7`, so a scale of 30 should be about right.

Also note that by using `x1 = x2 +300; y1 = y2 +300;` you change the transformations and get a *different* fractal (at a scale at which you expect).

Comment: Finally I got right fractal!! :) Thanks for explanation, now I see my mistakes

Comment: nice Jan! I thought about this too, but I made the mistake to keep using scaled values `xp, yp` for the fractal and gave up solving this :).

Answer (score 4):

This is great, I was wrong thinking that exponential runtime required! The fractals appeared more dimensional than my imagination!

Thanks @Jan Dvorak!

The following also works (in my coordinates, `xcenter=300`, `ycenter=100` and `radius=50` are global drawing parameters) and works faster:

```
void drawFractal2(Graphics g) {

        double x1 = 0;
        double y1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;
        double p;

        g.fillOval(xcenter + (int) (x1 * radius), ycenter + (int) (y1 * radius), 3, 3);

        for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i) {
            p = Math.random();

            if (p < p1) {
                x2 = x1(x1, y1);
                y2 = y1(x1, y1);

            }
            else {
                x2 = x2(x1, y1);
                y2 = y2(x1, y1);

            }

            g.fillOval(xcenter + (int) (x2 * radius), ycenter + (int) (y2 * radius), 3, 3);
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
        }

    }
```

and the picture is better

[image]

Comment: Thanks for testing my fix, buddy :-)

Comment: Note that "tree-like runtime" is, technically, nonsense. You can have "tree-like recursion", which then experiences "exponential runtime" ;)

Comment: Would you mind giving me some credit in the answer?

Comment: Sure I have already put my plus to it

Comment: I meant, saying within the answer what the problem with asker's code actually is and who found the problem ;-)

Comment: @Jan I said thanks to you in the answer, but I don't want to make full explanation since this was your part. My part is working code. Let people plus me for code while your answer will be the winner.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Thanks for code example, it was easier understand what is wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

**BELOW IS MY INCORRECT ANSWER**

But it show how fractals are bigger than the intuition, so I keep it.

I guess your algorithm should be tree-like (recursive) while your one is linear. You are just drawing one chain of points, transforming it one after one. So you get some spiral-like chain. It can't generate any fractal picture in principle.

**I GOT YOUR PICTURE**

You have 2 mistakes:

1) you pass 300 both into iteration and as drawing shift. This is minor.

2) You algorithm is linear. Linear algorithm can't draw tree-like picture. If you use random values, you should run algorithm multiple times. One chain draws only one random portion of the picture.

I got your picture with following recursive algorithm. It works slow but you are to improve it.

```
  void drawFractal(Graphics g, double x1, double y1, int depth) {

        double x2 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;

        if( depth > 20 ) {
            return;
        }

        g.fillOval(xcenter + (int) (x1 * radius), ycenter + (int) (y1 * radius), 3, 3);

        x2 = x1(x1, y1);
        y2 = y1(x1, y1);
        drawFractal(g, x2, y2, depth+1);



        x2 = x2(x1, y1);
        y2 = y2(x1, y1);
        drawFractal(g, x2, y2, depth+1);






    }
```

to run it I used

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //drawFractal(g);
        drawFractal(g, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

parameters are

```
    int xcenter = 300;
    int ycenter = 100;

    int radius = 50;
```

the picture is follows:

[image]

Comment: This is how IFS works. Note the transformation is chosen at random from a set of two - one transformation would, indeed, not be enough.

Comment: No, you are wrong. Choosing random won't help.

Comment: Read up on [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) or do some hand simulation. That's the beauty of _Iterated_ Function Systems.

Comment: @Jan don't teach just solve the problem. I solved it, while you didn't. Practice is the criterion of truth.

Comment: "You algorithm is linear. Linear algorithm can't draw tree-like picture." -- still wrong.

Comment: You solved (or, more correctly, avoided) the issue but not in the way you think.

Comment: @Jan may be terms are wrong but idea is not. You won't jump with one "mandelobus" over entire complex picture.

Comment: @Jan what a problem? you can solve in the way YOU think!

Comment: Your claim that you need manual branching is incorrect. You solved the problem by applying the correct scale - which the asker didn't - not by switching to tree-like recursion.

Comment: Note that your drawing algorithm totally neglects the `probability` coefficient.

Comment: "you pass 300 both into iteration and as drawing shift. This is minor." -- This is not minor, nor does he do it (outside of the comments).

Comment: Hm, looks like you are right, this is great!